# Функции для трансформации (вращения) вертексов

Tags: c++, directx

Только начинаю изучать `DirectX`. Подскажите, есть ли встроенные функции для поворота вертексов?

Есть массив вертексов, описывающих трехмерный объект. Часть из них я хочу повернуть вокруг какой-то оси на определенный угол. В принципе это сделать не сложно при помощи матриц преобразования. Но мне почему-то кажется, что в DirectX для этого есть встроенные функции. Может кто-то знает?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Спасибо,XMVector3Rotate как раз то, что искал.